# Go back to root navigator from a nested TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

This is how my hierachy looks,

```
-StackNavigator (root)
    -Portada
    -MainScreen (TabNavigator)
        -Home
        -Cronograma
        -Perfil
    -Login
    -Register
```

I navigate to Portada -> Main Screen -> Perfil,
Now I want to go back from Perfil to Portada again how I can do it?

Comment: did you tried to `navigate`?

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate from any sub-component using `this.props.navigation.navigate('Portada')` considering that you have defined `Portada` route in your navigation declaration.

The `navigation` prop is passed in props by default to all child components from parent component.

> For more details see documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html

Answer (score 0):

Reset stack navigator:

```
 this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Portada'})
   ]
 });

this.props.navigation.navigate('Portada');
```

Comment: If I use `this.props.navigation.goBack();` it takes me to the HomeTab, but I use your code it does not work at all, I'm at the same screen.

Comment: Then try to reset stack navigator.

Comment: I tried it too but no success, did u use it on your project or maybe has an example

Comment: If you got blank screen using my above code then try my updated code.

Comment: it is not easy, I think there is more disccussion here -> https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/335

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(“Portada”)
```

It will work!

Answer (score 0):

Use `screenProps` to pass Parent Navigation.

Example:

```
<TabbarRoot screenProps = {{ navi : this.props.naviagtion }}>
```

In Screen within Tabbar:

```
this.props.screenProps.navi.popToTop()
```

this will navigate back to Root Navigator.